# Java synchronized function work while synchronized block not work

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

takeAmount and addAmount is simply to add/sub value from balanceAccount(eg. add 11,12...,20 or add 101,102...,110). balanceAccount have two version one is using synchronized function and other is using synchronized block.

Is that any different between BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock and BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction?

Indeed BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction always return 0, while BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock doesn't.

And...why it will show different behavior?

```
public class mainStart {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        for (int i=1;i<3000;i=i+10)
        {
            new Thread(new addAmount(i)).start();
            new Thread(new takeAmount(i)).start();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock.printAmount();
        BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction.printAmount();
    }


}

class takeAmount implements Runnable {
    private int startFrom;

    public takeAmount(int start)
    {
        this.startFrom=start;
    }

    public void run() 
    {   
        for (int i=startFrom;i<startFrom+10;i++)
            //BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock.sub(i);
            BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction.sub(i);
    }

}

class addAmount implements Runnable {
    private int startFrom;

    public addAmount(int start)
    {
        this.startFrom=start;
    }

    public void run() 
    {   
        for (int i=startFrom;i<startFrom+10;i++)
            //BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock.add(i);
            BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction.add(i);
    }

}

public class BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock {
    public static Integer amount=0;

    public static void add(int a)
    {
        synchronized (amount)
        {
            amount = amount + a;
        }
    }

    public static void sub(int a)
    {
        synchronized (amount)
        {
            amount = amount - a;
        }
    }

    public synchronized static void printAmount()
    {
        System.out.println("Amount " + amount);
    }

}

public class BalanceAccount_synchronizedFunction {
    public static Integer amount=0;

    public synchronized static void add(int a)
    {
            amount = amount + a;
    }

    public synchronized static void sub(int a)
    {
            amount = amount - a;
    }

    public synchronized static void printAmount()
    {
        System.out.println("Amount " + amount);
    }

}
```

Comment: What different behavior does it show?

Comment: Don't synchronize on `Integer`, since it's immutable, you'll be synchronizing on different objects when `amount` is replaced, which can lead to interesting problems. You can use an `Object lock = new Object();` to synchronize on instead.

Comment: Thank for reply. It work.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronizing a method uses the enclosing class as a synchronization token. When you write `synchronized(amount)` you are using an `Integer` instance as a synchronization token. As you are not using the same token in both cases, the lock will not occur as expected.

Also note that `Integer` is immutable, and every time you reassign a value into `amount`, you are creating a new instance an lose whatever lock you may have had on the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Your print method is defined as

```
public synchronized static void printAmount()
```

which is synchronized *on the class itself*. In the case of your "block" attempt, the blocks are synchronizing on `amount`, while the print method is synchronizing on the class. Change that method to use a block also synchronized on `amount`.

As **Kayaman** pointed out, you also have the problem that you're synchronizing on a variable (`amount`) whose referent is constantly changing. Instead, declare a `private static final Object LOCK = new Object()` that is used only for synchronization--or better yet, just use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Thank for reply, I try you suggestion and it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either lock using object which is calling this method by using

```
synchronized (this) { // this is similar to method level synchronization
```

Or using another class level Object other then amount integer(as **@Kayaman** pointed out, it is immutable so every time new integer object is created when you update it)

```
public class BalanceAccount_synchronizedBlock {
    public static Integer amount=0;
    public static Object Lock = new Object();

    public static void add(int a) {
        synchronized (Lock) {
            amount = amount + a;
        }
    }
```